# Evolution : relaying denied in ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: evolution

I'm using ubuntu 14.04.1 and when using evolution as E-mail client I recieve the following message when sending mail :

relaying denied.

What can I do to resolve this problem please, I never in the past had an error like this???

Kind regards,

Steven.

Answer (score 0):

This error is a very common error which comes from the mail server you are trying to send email through.

Possible reasons include

- username / password for server not set
- you use the mailserver of your ISP but are connected through another ISP

Call your ISP / the server admin and ask them how to proceed.